# How to create Web Application using C# and ASP.NET Core using macOS X

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I'm the beginner in C# and in ASP.NET Core and I have a task to create Web Application.
The main task of this app is basic: I need to create a form(line where user can write something) and display written content. Also it mush handle exceptions(FormatException)
when user doesn't input a number

Code snippet for Console Application I have developed and now I need to transform it into Web Application with the help of C# and ASP.NET Core framework.

Here the code template of C# Console Application:

```
using System;
namespace Input_Output
{
   class MainClass
   {
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        int number;
        try 
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
           number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
           Console.WriteLine($"You've entered {number}");
        }
        catch(FormatException)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("It is not a number!!!");
        }
        Console.ReadKey(true);
     }
   }
}
```

And now I need to transform it into the Web Application with the line for input and if it is not a numeric value like 10, 49, etc than display exception in the special window. I am writing this on macOS X, so don't give pieces of advice for Windows :)

Hope someone could help me with this task. Thank you :) :) :)

Comment: You need to decide first what's the web framework you want to use, ASP.NET Core MVC? Blazor? Or simply a JavaScript one like React. For your simple requirements above, all of them can be used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    int number;
    try 
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
       var enteredNumber = Console.ReadLine();
       var isNumeric = int.TryParse(enteredNumber, out int n);
       if(isNumeric)
       {
         number = Convert.ToInt32(enteredNumber);
         Console.WriteLine($"You've entered {number} succesfully");
       }
       else
       {
         Console.WriteLine("It is not a number!!!");
       }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("An issue occured with your number entry: " + ex.message);
    }
    Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: I made a change just now, previous code was incorrect near the TryParse line of code.

Comment: But it is console app but I need Web App
I have two files: Program.cs and Startup.cs
In what of this following and where should I put this code

Comment: What steps I should follow in order to get the full Web App with the different features and functionality? This code is using in console but not in Web, I need it to display on the localhost website. And I don't know how to do it

Comment: I would start by following a beginner tutorial (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/asp.net_core_quick_guide.htm) and learning the basics. You will need to create a front end view that shows the input box for the number (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/asp.net_core_razor_view_start.htm) and then handle their input through a action result (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/asp.net_core_action_results.htm).

Comment: Is this an answer? If not, delete it and edit the question to include such extra information.